# Selenium Chrome Driver » 3.2.0

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-serenity

I am an automation tester using Cucumber, Serenity and Gradle.
I just updated my `build.gradle` properties file to use *[Selenium Chrome Driver » 3.2.0]* and ran my login test and found an error that has not occurred in *[Selenium Chrome Driver » 3.0.1]*.

I also get the same error when using 3.1.0
compile group: `'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.1.0'`.

I moved back to version 3.0.1 which works without any issues.
Here is the error message I get:

```
net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.servicepools.DriverServiceExecutable.asAFile(DriverServiceExecutable.java:90)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.servicepools.GeckoDriverServiceExecutable.geckoBinaryCalled(GeckoDriverServiceExecutable.java:38)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.servicepools.GeckoDriverServiceExecutable.executablePath(GeckoDriverServiceExecutable.java:24)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.servicepools.GeckoDriverServiceExecutable.inEnvironment(GeckoDriverServiceExecutable.java:20)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.servicepools.GeckoServicePool.configureGeckoDriverBinaries(GeckoServicePool.java:38)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.servicepools.GeckoServicePool.<init>(GeckoServicePool.java:29)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.FirefoxDriverProvider.<init>(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:29)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.driverProviders(WebDriverFactory.java:102)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:126)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:144)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:135)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:105)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.openIgnoringHtmlUnitScriptErrors(WebDriverFacade.java:180)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.get(WebDriverFacade.java:175)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.openPageAtUrl(PageObject.java:829)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.openAt(PageObject.java:782)
    at faa.cucumber.stepLibraries.BaseUserSteps.navigateToTheFaaHomePage(BaseUserSteps.java:60)
    at faa.cucumber.stepLibraries.BaseUserSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9ba37e92.CGLIB$navigateToTheFaaHomePage$26(<generated>)
    at faa.cucumber.stepLibraries.BaseUserSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9ba37e92$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7f7ccb1e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:372)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:357)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:332)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:134)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:61)
    at faa.cucumber.stepLibraries.BaseUserSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9ba37e92.navigateToTheFaaHomePage(<generated>)
    at faa.cucumber.maps.NavigationMap.given_welcome(NavigationMap.java:197)
    at ✽.Given i have accessed the welcome page(login.feature:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.0.1'

I'm not using Selenium.  I'm using Gradle, Cucumber, Serenity.

Comment: Not using selenium?  Did you mean Maven?

Comment: I'm not using Selenium. I'm using Gradle, Cucumber, Serenity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using maven. I'm using Created a gradle project, write cucumber feature files, then write java map, steps and page classes.
I then run my tests using git-bash at the command line.
My tests run and create a serenity report .
Have been doing it this way for 3 years.

Here is part of my build.gradle file to show my current chrome driver.  When I update the driver to 3.2.0, I get that error message as previously posted.

compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.0.1'